# Configure Postfix to only allow outgoing mail from localhost

Tags: postfix, email-server

How do I configure the Postfix mail submission agent to only allow emails to be sent out from a user on localhost , but allow the Postfix mail transfer agent to receive mail from anywhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest way is to make sure you have only localhost defined in `mynetworks`:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
```

By default `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is set as:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

This will allow hosts defined in `mynetworks` (localhost, as above) to send anywhere, while everything else is rejected unless it's destined for your box or otherwise explicitly allowed (relay domains, virtual domains, or whatever other configurations you're allowing.)

Comment: With the above, this seems to have stopped me sending to external domains.  When sending I now get 554 5.7.1 <user@domain.com>: Relay access denied

Comment: My bad!  Doing this logged in to the box works fine.  It was failing when I was trying to do this by tunnelling via ssh to the mail server.  I thought this would have been equivalent to being on the box.